# Unit testing http.get call with dynamic response in angular

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to unit test the `http.get` calls with actual response and not by mocking the response?

```
...
export class CarService{
    ...
    getCars():Observable<any>{
        return this.http.get("http://someurl/cars").map( res => res.json() );
    }
    ...
}
```

Unit test:

```
it('retrieves all the cars', injectAsync( [CarService], ( carService ) => {
  return carService.getCars().toPromise().then( (result) => {         
     expect(result.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
  } );       
}) );
```

It will execute the `http.get` call and it will pause for few seconds and then it will return the below error:

> Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working by adding below snippet inside the beforeEachProviders -

```
beforeEachProviders(() => {
    window.jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 10000;
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('inside timeout');
    }, 500);
```

this will remove the time out error and you can test the actual dynamic response coming from API.

Answer (score 0):

Dependencies in a unit test should be mocked away. Unit testing, as the
name suggests, should test the unit and not its dependencies.